# Set tests order while running tests in parallel

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-xdist, pytest-order

i have 5 test classes, and one of them (the 5th one) i want to run the last one.

Each test processes data. The last test cannot run while the data is being processed by any other test.

I tried to use the following:
`pytest-order`, `pytest-ordering` and `@pytest.mark.xdist_group(name="group1")`

i tried to define a global variable (in `conftest.py`) and use it with a fixture as a flag when a class is done with tests.

In other words, i want to set the order in which the workers are executed.

Comment: `pytest-order` does not define the order in which the workers are executed - dependencies between modules won't work with `pytest-xdist`, and dependencies in modules only if using [--dist=loadfile](https://pytest-order.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other_plugins.html#usage-with-pytest-xdist).